# Multiple protocol and class inheritance confusion, Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

So I know a class can only inherit a single class but can inherit multiple protocols. I am looking at some code here and confused as to why swift is throwing me an error.

```
protocol PaymentViewModelConfigurable: ViewModelWithResult {
    
}

class ViewModelWithResult {
    func printWithResultClass() {
        print("In View Model with result class")
    }
}

class PaymentViewModel: PaymentViewModelConfigurable {
    
    
}


class MainOne {
    let viewModel: PaymentViewModelConfigurable = PaymentViewModel()
}
```

So I would assume this is ok because my `PaymentViewModel` class inherits a protocol and that protocol inherits from a class.

But if I change the logic to this on my ViewModel to inherit the protocol & the class, its fine

```
protocol PaymentViewModelConfigurable: ViewModelWithResult {
    func payments()
}

class ViewModelWithResult {
    func printWithResultClass() {
        print("In View Model with result class")
    }
}

class PaymentViewModel: ViewModelWithResult, PaymentViewModelConfigurable {
    func payments() {
        print("Payments")
    }
}


class MainOne {
    let viewModel: PaymentViewModelConfigurable = PaymentViewModel()
    
    init() {
        viewModel.payments()
    }
}
```

These are the errors that come up:

> 'PaymentViewModelConfigurable' requires that 'PaymentViewModel' inherit from 'ViewModelWithResult'

> Type 'PaymentViewModel' does not conform to protocol 'PaymentViewModelConfigurable'

Comment: Please post code as text, not images of text.

Comment: And if you are going to ask about errors, please show them as well.  (I know they were in the original image, but lost in the translation to text.)

Comment: how can I show the errors through code?

Comment: @SimonMcNeil Up to you! You can either put them as comment inline to where the errors appear, or paste them in a separate snippet below the rest of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I know a class can only inherit a single class but can inherit multiple protocols.

Not quite. A class can *conform to* multiple protocols. It might seem like a pedantic correction of wording, but it's actually core to the issue here. The conformance and inheritance features are related and interconnected, but distinct. Similarly:

> and that protocol inherits from a class.

It doesn't.

Everything after the `:` on a declaration of a protocol is not a list of superclasses and protocol conformances, like with classes. It's a list of *requirements* of that protocol. So this declaration:

```
protocol PaymentViewModelConfigurable: ViewModelWithResult {
    func payments()
}
```

Is saying: "`PaymentViewModelConfigurable` is a protocol that can be conformed to anything that's a subtype of `ViewModelWithResult` and has a `func payments()` method. It's as if you had written:

```swift
protocol PaymentViewModelConfigurable where Self: ViewModelWithResult {
    func payments()
}
```

The error messages spell this out quite explicitly:

```
Untitled 4.swift:11:7: error: 'PaymentViewModelConfigurable' requires that 'PaymentViewModel' inherit from 'ViewModelWithResult'
class PaymentViewModel: PaymentViewModelConfigurable {
      ^
Untitled 4.swift:11:7: note: requirement specified as 'Self' : 'ViewModelWithResult' [with Self = PaymentViewModel]
class PaymentViewModel: PaymentViewModelConfigurable {
      ^
```

Comment: putting the `where Self:` instead helped me understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: @SimonMcNeil I think you forgot a part of your comment