# Different Protocol with similar property name

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a class **bird** which confirms two protocols **swim** and **fly**. Both the protocol have similar property called **Speed**. As Bird can fly with some speed also birds can swim with some speed. I am confirming both the protocol in one class **bird**.

My question is

a) How can I distinguish between both the speed (If I want to keep similar names of properties) ?

b)In the current code snippet under class bird there is a property **speed**, to which protocol this property is referring to (Fly or Swim)?

c) How can I know flying speed and swimming speed in this scenario?

```
protocol Fly {
    var speed: Int { get set }
}


protocol Swim {
    var speed: Int { get set }
}


class Bird: Fly, Swim
{
    var speed: Int = 0 <-------- Is this from protocol swim or from Fly 
     
}
```

Comment: As long as there is no protocol extension which uses `speed` it’s irrelevant where `speed` belongs to. And even with a protocol extension the compiler should be smart enough to distinguish the type.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you want to have both air speed and water speed for an animal which adopts both protocols then you need to use different property names. Currently there is only one `speed`, which is shared by both protocols in an animal which adopts both protocols.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like you've misinterpreted the concept of protocol. Very
straightfowardly, a protocol states what properties (`speed` in your example) and methods *something* (the `Bird` class, in your example) **must** have in order to conform to it. Any type that satisfies the requirements of a protocol is said to *conform* to that protocol. Protocols are an important concept in the delegate pattern.

So, I'll answer to your **b)** question first: since your `Bird` class have a `speed` property, it conforms to both protocols. That's because your protocols have different names but define the same blueprint of properties that the class must have. That would not be true in the following case:

```
protocol Fly {
    var speed: Int { get set }
}

protocol Swim {
    var speed: Int { get set }
    func startSwimming() 
}

// you'll get a compiler error here
class Bird: Fly, Swim 
{
    var speed: Int = 0    
//    uncommenting these lines will solve the compiler error
//    func startSwimming() 
//    {
//         print("started to swim")
//    }
}
```

The class then conforms to the `Fly` protocol, but not to the `Swim` protocol. You need to add the `startSwimming()` method, in my example, or you'll get an error from the compiler here. It would be the same if instead of a method the `Swim` protocol included another property.

**a)** question: you can't, in your example. One solution would be to split `speed` into two different properties, like this:

```
protocol Fly {
    var flyingSpeed: Int { get set }
}

protocol Swim {
    var swimmingSpeed: Int { get set }
}
 
class Bird: Fly, Swim
{
    var flyingSpeed: Int = 0
    var swimmingSpeed: Int = 0
}
```

Or, just to show you a convention to write code - note that it's the same of the above code:

```
class Bird
{ 
    // ...
}

extension Bird: Fly 
{
    var flyingSpeed: Int = 0
}

extension Bird: Swim 
{
    var swimmingSpeed: Int = 0
}
```

Not sure about what you meant with your **c)** question. If I understood it correctly, of course you can't create an instance of a protocol, something like `let swim = Swim()` makes no sense. You can however create a `bird` object and access both properties from it.

```
let bird = Bird()
print(bird.flyingSpeed) // this will print 0 in the console
print(bird.swimmingSpeed) // this will print 0 in the console
bird.flyingSpeed = 4 
bird.swimmingSpeed = 3
print(bird.flyingSpeed) // this will print 4 in the console
print(bird.swimmingSpeed) // this will print 3 in the console
```

If however you were asking about the delegate pattern, shortly, it is used to "communicate" between classes. You can find lot of clear explanations about it just by searching on Google. Just a few suggestions:

1. [StackOverflow related question and answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099230/delegates-in-swift)
2. [YouTube tutorial by iOS Academy about delegate pattern.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2x2Yjoe-T4)

Comment: "Any type that satisfies the requirements of a protocol is said to conform to that protocol" That is possibly misleading. The type must _formally adopt_ the protocol in order to conform to it. Merely having a `speed` property does not give a type any relationship at all to Swim or Fly.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this from protocol Swim or from Fly

Neither. It's a property on `Bird` which satisfies *both* `Swim` or `Fly`. Protocol conformance is different from class inheritance. I clarify this a bit in this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632019/3141234

Comment: You're right, OP intended protocol conformance as the same of class inheritance, that's the reason of his ambiguous questions. I guess once OP understand this all his questions are cleared, I wrote a bunch of lines in my answer but this should actually be the accepted one lol.

Comment: @oneshot Yeah, it's a common misunderstanding that I've seen before. Your answer it good, I upvoted it :)